# Match Systeminfo | findstr "Memory" output with regex

Tags: regex, windows-7

This is the output:

```
Total Physical Memory:     3,840 MB
Available Physical Memory:   889 MB
Virtual Memory: Max Size:  7,677 MB
Virtual Memory: Available: 4,533 MB
Virtual Memory: In Use:    3,144 MB
```

I want to fetch:

```
Total Physical Memory
Available Physical Memory
Virtual Memory: Max Size 
Virtual Memory: Available
Virtual Memory: In Use
```

separately.

Comment: You want to fetch each of those values separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like this:

```
/^[A-Za-z\s:]+(?=:\s*\d+(,\d{3})*\s[MK]B)/
```

You'll want to make sure your regex matcher is set to interpret `^` as the beginning of a line, not the whole string. This is usually set as an option somewhere.

Depending on your regex flavor, you may also have to escape the `:` in `[A-Za-z\s:]`.

**EDIT:** Here's an explanation:

```
^             #The beginning of a line
[A-Za-z\s:]+  #Any number of letters, spaces, and/or `:` characters, but at least one.
(?=...)       #A positive lookahead assertion, because we want to check for the presence of the upcoming pattern but not include it in our match.
:\s*          #A colon followed by any amount of whitespace.
\d+(,\d{3})*  #A number in X,XXX,XXX format, with any number of ,XXX groups.
\s[MK]B       #A space, then either MB or KB.
```

Hopefully that's fairly clear. If you need it, [here's some info on lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: @Abhishek - Actually there was an extra `)`. My bad, try it now.

Comment: I'll try in some time.. and yes of course, I won't forget to mark your answer as correct if it works :)